# ¿cómo puedo concatenar dos datos de dos tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

He estado probando de varias maneras mas no puedo, el query es el siguiente:

```
   select asd_pendientes.id_alumno as 'ID', 
           asd_clientes.nombre,
           asd_pendientes.tipo, 
           asd_pendientes.llave,
           asd_pendientes.debe  from asd_pendientes 
                                inner join asd_clientes 
                                on asd_clientes.codigo = asd_pendientes.cliente
                                inner join uni_notas  
                             on CONCAT(uni_notas.semestre, '', (select codigo from uni_cursos inner join uni_cursos on uni_cursos = uni_notas.id_curso)) As 'Llave' From uni_notas = asd_pendientes.llave 
                             where asd_pendientes.tipo = 'C' 
                             order by asd_pendientes.llave desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeramente debes dar más detalles, ¿qué campos quieres concatenar? ¿cuántas tablas tienes y qué campos tiene cada una? (si puedes, con muestra de cada dato mejor). Puedes también cargar archivos y compartirlos para que los veamos.

Para concatenar 2 o más campos, basta que los unas o concatenes durante `SELECT` (no en los joins)

ejemplos:

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.apellidos, a.nombres, a.género) from alumnos as a;
```

Dará como resultado *"Lopez PerezErnestomasculino"* porque has juntado esos campos y no pusimos espacios entre ellos. Si quieres espacios pondrías espacios entre ellos o usarías `CONCAT_WS`, que te permite usar un separador entre campos en el primer argumento, ejemplo:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', a.apellidos, nombres, género) from alumnos as a;
```

Así es como se concatena para verlo. Aparentemente en tu query, lo que estás haciendo es querer concatenar para unir, pero eso ocurre en la condición de unión (join) y no es visible en los resultados.

(También puedes unir con operadores de concatenación en lugar de la función concatenar, ejemplos de operadores de concatenación: oracle "`||`", mssql "`+`", php "`.`", etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas dar mas detalle de lo que realmente quieres hacer como que gestor de base de datos etc, de acuerdo a lo que entiendo de tu pregunta se puede concatenar campos de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT 
tbA.campo1 + tbB.campo1 as campoConcatenado

FROM tbA, tbB

WHERE tbB.id = tbB.id;
```

si usas oracle se puede concatenar de la siguiente manera si mas y no me equivo tiene ya un rato que use oracle:

```
SELECT 
tbA.campo1 || tbB.campo1 as campoConcatenado

FROM tbA, tbB

WHERE tbB.id = tbB.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, tienes a mi parecer tienes un error en la unión entre las tablas uni_notas y asd_pendientes que no deberia funcionar en teoría, nunca lo habia visto así para ser sincero. Pero hasta donde se no puedes unir dos tablas usando una concatenación de valores, este pareo debe ser solo con los campos de las tablas referenciadas, es decir

```
select pendientes.id_alumno as 'ID', 
       clientes.nombre,
       pendientes.tipo, 
       pendientes.llave,
       pendientes.debe  
from asd_pendientes pendientes inner join asd_clientes clientes
       on clientes.codigo = pendientes.cliente
       inner join uni_notas notas 
       on notas.campo_en_comun = pendientes.campo_en_comun 
where pendientes.tipo = 'C' 
order by pendientes.llave desc
```

Y te recomiendo el uso de alias para las tablas, te ayudara a ordenar la consulta, si el dato mediante el cual quieres unir dos tablas, en realidad no es un campo, entonces debieras hacerlo como dice J. Armando, sin el uso de join y haciendo el pareo entre campos mediante un where, donde si puedes utilizar la funcion concatenar, por ejemplo

```
select t1.dato_1 as id,
       t2.dato_2 as dato2,
       tn.dato_n as dato_n
from tabla_1 t1,
     tabla_2 t2,
     tabla_n tn
where t1.dato = t2.dato
  and t2.dato = tn.dato
  and concat(concat(tn.dato, ' '), tn.dato_1) = t1.dato
```

y hago incapie en el uso de alias, espero poder haberte sido útil, saludos